# How many times did Robert Creamer visit Obama's White House?

Tags: united-states, voting, lobbying

How many times did [Robert Creamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Creamer_(political_consultant)) visit Obama's White House?

The context of the question are two facts related to 2016 US Presidential election:

1. That there is an ongoing scandal over Robert Creamer's actions as part of Hillary Clinton's Presidential campaign (detailed [at CNN article here](http://www.cnn.com/2016/10/18/politics/project-veritas-action-robert-creamer-donald-trump-rallies/), in short, there are videos which are interpreted as planning to disrupt Trump rallies and plant protestors).
2. There is a separate ongoing scandal over allegations of voter fraud. From Wikipedia:

   > In October 2016, conservative activist James O'Keefe's Project Veritas Action released hidden-camera videos appearing to show Creamer and others who worked for firms hired by the Hillary Clinton campaign engaging in hypothetical conversations about voter registration. **One clip in the video shows Creamer meeting with an undercover activist posing as a potential donor. After the actor suggests finding a way around voter registration laws, Creamer responds "my fear is that someone would decide that this is a big voter fraud scheme."**

Comment: @user4012 I think you accidentally a word.

Comment: The title does not seem to match the question. Am I missing something?

Comment: Creamer also tied himself to massive voter fraud and is a convicted felon

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - missed that. Fixed.

Comment: Got a reference for that "massive voter fraud"? And no, being a felon for completely unrelated crimes does not count.

Comment: The same video shows Mr. Creamer discussing a proposal by a Project Veritas investigator to register people to vote illegally by setting up a shell corporation. http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2016/oct/18/undercover-video-shows-democrats-saying-they-hire-/

Comment: http://www.snopes.com/2016/10/19/scott-foval-reportedly-fired-from-political-organization-over-sting-videos/

Comment: @KDog That's not evidence of "massive voter fraud", it's not even evidence of conspiracy to commit voter fraud...

Comment: Registering people illegally isn't committing voter fraud?

Comment: @KDog If there are people being registered to vote illegally, that article/video showed none of it... And considering only 31 credible instances of voter fraud have been since 2000, that comes as no real surprise.

Comment: 113 convictions in one State, MN, in just one year, 2011.  Not sure where you get your figures  http://www.minnesotamajority.org/minnesota-leads-the-nation-in-voter-fraud-convictions/

Comment: It's a widely reported figure from a study which corroborates what most experts say. Here's just one report on it: https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonk/wp/2014/08/06/a-comprehensive-investigation-of-voter-impersonation-finds-31-credible-incidents-out-of-one-billion-ballots-cast/ (Also, Minnesota Majority is an activist group, and not exactly a credible source.)

Comment: @user4012 Never mind; I think the post got saved while you were editing it so I saw it in mid-edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Daily Caller article](http://dailycaller.com/2016/10/18/exposed-dem-operative-who-oversaw-trump-rally-agitators-visited-white-house-342-times/) alleges it was 342 times since 2009, citing "White House records".

*Caveat Emptor*, since DC is an openly right of center media outfit. The article did not provide material proof of the count (scanned records, or citation to what can be considered likely-neutral source, etc...).

> Robert Creamer, who acted as a middle man between the Clinton campaign, the Democratic National Committee and “protesters” who tried — and succeeded — to provoke violence at Trump rallies met with President Obama during 47 of those 342 visits, according to White House records. Creamer’s last visit was in June 2016.

Comment: If anyone has a better reference, please speak up (short of filing FOIA request).

Answer (score 6):

### Apparently: 323

This information is publicly available through the [White House's Visitor Access Records](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/disclosures/visitor-records).

After downloading and unzipping the CSV files to a directory, a quick Unix command line reveals the number of entries with this name:

```
$ grep -i 'Creamer' * | grep -i 'Robert' | wc -l
     323
```

So there are 323 entries since these records have been published in 2009. The records don't offer much information on the nature of these visits though, so I'm not sure they are particularly noteworthy.